# Ошибка 0xc0000142 при подключении DLL

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, windows-10

У меня есть проект на C++ в Visual Studio. В .cpp файле я добавила `#include "mylib.h"` , в линковщике указала mylib.lib, и в папку с exe положила mylib.dll. Тем не менее, приложение не запускается и выдаёт ошибку 0xc0000142. В чём может быть проблема и как это исправить?
Библиотека от стороннего производителя, который утверждает, что на его компе работает.

Answer (score 0):

Библиотека mylib.dll зависит от каких-то третьих библиотек (.dll), которых нет на вашей мащшине, или они более новой версии библиотек, или версия присланная вам .lib не соотвествует .dll...  Наиболее вероятно, что вам нужно поставить С++runtime нужной версии.

Проанализировать зависимоcти можно, например, с помощью [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).